# How import and export RSAParameters keys to file without making a change to the keys in C#

Tags: c#, digital-signature, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm writing a digital signing program using `C#` and I use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class that generates public and private keys and signatures depending on the file. If in the program, I check the signature with the public key, signature and file, it works correctly but If I save my keys to any format in the file, In other words, I will change their format and return to the first state It doesn't work. because I can not turn it into `RSAParameters` correctly. please guide me?

Simple example test to show the change:

```
var publicParams = rsaWrite.ExportParameters(false); // Generate the public key.
var testpublicParams = publicParams;
string st = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(publicParams.Modulus);
testpublicParams.Modulus = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(st);
if(publicParams.Modulus != testpublicParams.Modulus) { 
                Console.WriteLine("The key has been changed.");
}
```

Comment: You have to de- / serialize the whole `RSAParameters` object for loading saving. Easiest would be Newtonsoft `JsonConvert`.

Comment: Any chance you can use [PemUtils](https://github.com/huysentruitw/pem-utils) for this instead?

Comment: @huysentruitw It sounds good, Thank you.

Comment: @Oliver I'll see it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has two problems:

1. The use of `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` is wrong because  it might have a non-ASCII characters so we use the `Convert.ToBase64String`.
2. `publicParams.Modulus` is C# byte array so `!=` probably not the right answer so we use `SequenceEqual`.

And the key will not change.

```
var rsaWrite = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var publicParams = rsaWrite.ExportParameters(false); // Generate the public key.
var testpublicParams = publicParams;
string st = Convert.ToBase64String(publicParams.Modulus);
testpublicParams.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(st);
if (!publicParams.Modulus.SequenceEqual(testpublicParams.Modulus))
{
     Console.WriteLine("The key has been changed.");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("The key has not been changed. :D");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get PublicKey as string format and save it on the other text file.

```
public static string PublicKey(string certSubject)
        {
            var my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
            byte[] publicKeyByte = null;
            foreach (var cert in my.Certificates)
            {
                if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
                {
                    csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
                    publicKeyByte = cert.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
                }
            }
            if (csp == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("No valid cert was found");
            }
            var publicKey = new StringBuilder();
            publicKey.AppendLine("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");
            publicKey.AppendLine(Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyByte, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
            publicKey.AppendLine("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
            return publicKey.ToString();
        }
```